# How to append values to a list of lists using other list of lists and doing mathematical operations

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, append

I have several lists of lists:

```
crt = [[80, 90, 6, 5.4, 8, 5], [65, 58, 2, 9.7, 1, 1], [83, 60, 4, 7.2, 4, 7],
       [40, 80, 10, 7.5, 7, 10], [52, 72, 6, 2, 3, 8], [94, 96, 7, 3.6, 5, 6]]

nc = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1],
      [2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 6], [10, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0], [0, 30, 5, 3, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]]

DivMatrix = [[[0, -15, 3, -40, -28, 14], [15, 0, 18, -25, -13, 29],
              [-3, -18, 0, -43, -31, 11], [40, 25, 43, 0, 12, 54],
              [28, 13, 31, -12, 0, 42], [-14, -29, -11, -54, -42, 0]],
             [[0, 32, 30, 10, 18, -6], [-32, 0, -2, -22, -14, -38],
              [-30, 2, 0, -20, -12, -36], [-10, 22, 20, 0, 8, -16],
              [-18, 14, 12, -8, 0, -24], [6, 38, 36, 16, 24, 0]],
              [[0, -4, -2, 4, 0, 1], [4, 0, 2, 8, 4, 5],
              [2, -2, 0, 6, 2, 3], [-4, -8, -6, 0, -4, -3],
              [0, -4, -2, 4, 0, 1], [-1, -5, -3, 3, -1, 0]],
             [[-0.0, 4.299999999999999, 1.7999999999999998,
               2.0999999999999996, -3.4000000000000004, -1.8000000000000003],
              [-4.299999999999999, -0.0, -2.499999999999999,
               -2.1999999999999993, -7.699999999999999, -6.1],
              [-1.7999999999999998, 2.499999999999999, -0.0,
               0.2999999999999998, -5.2, -3.6], [-2.0999999999999996,
               2.1999999999999993, -0.2999999999999998, -0.0, -5.5, -3.9],
              [3.4000000000000004, 7.699999999999999, 5.2, 5.5, 0, 1.6],
              [1.8000000000000003, 6.1, 3.6, 3.9, -1.6, -0.0]],
             [[0, -7, -4, -1, -5, -3], [7, 0, 3, 6, 2, 4],
              [4, -3, 0, 3, -1, 1], [1, -6, -3, 0, -4, -2],
              [5, -2, 1, 4, 0, 2], [3, -4, -1, 2, -2, 0]],
             [[0, 4, -2, -5, -3, -1], [-4, 0, -6, -9, -7, -5],
              [2, 6, 0, -3, -1, 1], [5, 9, 3, 0, 2, 4], [3, 7, 1, -2, 0, 2],
              [1, 5, -1, -4, -2, 0]]]
```

I want to create a list of lists with the same size as `DivMatrix`. The creation must start with a for loop and then with 6 different if statements, each one of them representing a type equation with `nc[3]`. I want to build the first if statement and then I will build the others which are more complicated.I have this algorithm so far but it is wrong.

```
pref_indic = []
for x in range(len(crt)):
    if (nc[3][x] == 1):
        prolist = []
        for y in range(len(DivMatrix[x])):
            prolist2 = []
            for z in range(len(DivMatrix[x])):
                if (DivMatrix[y][z]<=0):
                    prolist2.append(0)
                else:
                    prolist2.append(1)
            prolist.append(prolist2)
            pref_indic.append(prolist)
    else:
       print "wrong function type"

print pref_indic
```

If the `nc[3][x] = 1`  which means if the type is type 1, then if the value in `DivMatrix[x]<=0` then append 0, else append 1.

So as a result, for `nc[3][4]` which is equal to 1, I will get the following list appended:

```
pref_indic[4] = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Sorry for the size of the post.

Comment: please fix indentation near `if (nc[3][x] == 1):
    prolist = []`

Comment: What is the Question?

Comment: @h_e_u_r_e_k_a i want to create pref_indic with 6 if, one of them will be the one i have above which i want to give the result as mentioned above. pref_indic[4] = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

Comment: Then write the other 5 if's.

Comment: @martineau the other 5 are really complicated, but if i figure out how to build only the one with type=1 i will easily create the others. So let the pref_indic have only the lists i write above for start, and when i do this, i will create the other 5 ifs

Comment: What's wrong with your current algorithm? Why do you have to use 6 if's, is this school work?

Comment: @martineau there must be 6 types, for each one of them there will be different mathematical operations, i mentioned the simplest one above appended with aces and zeros. It is actually for my paper.

Comment: what you want to do is very unclear, and your code is not more clear.
maybe you should first try to cut your different loops into functions with relevant names, you may also want to give relevant names to your data. it could help people to understand what you are trying to achieve; thus it could help you to obtain help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your code, modified just enough to do what you want (I guess, not sure):

```
pref_indic = []
for x in range(len(crt)):
    if (nc[3][x] == 1):
        prolist = []
        for y in range(len(DivMatrix[x])):
            prolist2 = []
            for z in range(len(DivMatrix[x][y])):
                if (DivMatrix[x][y][z]<=0):
                   prolist2.append(0)
                else:
                   prolist2.append(1)
            prolist.append(prolist2)
        pref_indic.append(prolist)
    else:
       pref_indic.append("wrong function type")

print pref_indic
```

---

here is now something more readable (but limited because I don't know what kind of data I am manipulating):

```
def process_eq_type_1(div_matrix_element):
    prolist = []
    for element_of_element in div_matrix_element:
        prolist2 = []
        for element_of_element_of_element in element_of_element:
            if element_of_element_of_element <= 0:
                prolist2.append(0)
            else:
                prolist2.append(1)
        prolist.append(prolist2)
    return prolist


def process_eq_type_2(div_matrix_element):
    return "eq type 2 not implemented"


def process_eq_type_3(div_matrix_element):
    return "eq type 3 not implemented"


pref_indic = []
for eq_type, unclear_data in zip(nc[3], DivMatrix):
    if (eq_type == 1):
        pref_indic.append(process_eq_type_1(unclear_data))
    elif (eq_type == 2):
        pref_indic.append(process_eq_type_2(unclear_data))
    elif (eq_type == 3):
        pref_indic.append(process_eq_type_3(unclear_data))
    else:
        pref_indic.append("wrong function type")


print pref_indic
```

it does quite exactly the same thing but:

1. the main loop is simplified by:

   - using [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) to link the two list to iterate and retrieving directly the wanted values instead of using an index
   - using [function](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) for each case to process (only the first kind of process is implemented, but more functions already exist)
   - using "explicit" names for variables
2. the processing code for the case where nc[3] == 1 is extracted in a function, improving readability
3. accessing data by indexes is banished as far as possible

it is far more readable and intelligible in my opinion (hope you will agree).

---

using some Python tricks you could make the process_eq_type_1 yet more concise:

```
def process_eq_type_1(div_matrix_element):
    prolist = []
    for element_of_element in div_matrix_element:
        prolist2 = []
        for element_of_element_of_element in element_of_element:
            prolist2.append(int(element_of_element_of_element > 0))
        prolist.append(prolist2)
    return prolist
```

or using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def process_eq_type_1(div_matrix_element):
    prolist = []
    for element_of_element in div_matrix_element:
        prolist.append([int(element_of_element_of_element > 0)
                        for element_of_element_of_element
                        in element_of_element])
    return prolist
```

---

**final advice**: you may want to read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: This would be the next step!! i wanted to first create a for loop with 6 if's and then convert it to 6 different functions!! :) really thank you! and yes that was exactly what i wanted to do!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
pref_indic = []
for x in range(len(crt)):
    if nc[3][x] == 1:
        prolist = []
        for y in range(len(DivMatrix[x])):
            prolist2 = []
            for z in range(len(DivMatrix[x][y])):
                if DivMatrix[x][y][z] <= 0:
                    prolist2.append(0)
                else:
                    prolist2.append(1)
            prolist.append(prolist2)
            pref_indic.append(prolist)
    elif nc[3][x] == 2:
        # add code here
    elif nc[3][x] == 3:
        # add code here
    elif nc[3][x] == 4:
        # add code here
    # ...etc
    else:
       print "wrong function type"

print pref_indic
```